# Python - Printing Reverse Name Order

Tags: python, join, reverse

If my list in a text file has the following

I want it to print out like

However my current code prints it out like

My code is:

```
def addStudent(student):
    reg,year,degree,*name= student.strip().split(" ")
    name = list(reversed(name))
    fullName = name[0] + ", " + " ".join(name[1:])
    return (reg,year,degree,name,fullName)

def employee(employee):
    reg,year,degree,*name,fullName = employe
    print(format(fullName, "<32s")+format(reg,"<7d")+format(degree,">6s"),format(thisYear,">6s"))
```

How do i switch the order of the last two parts of the name? In which area is my code wrong because i'm not sure how else to reverse it. If i do add a print statement after the reversed function it does seperate each part of the name as a string, but when it joins, it does it in the wrong order

Comment: its not the cleanest way but have you tried accessing the names by index

Comment: I could do, but the amount of "other names" varies so i can't be too precise with indexing

Comment: that did come to mind when i was actually trying to give it as answer

Answer (score 2):

Just don't reverse the list:

```
def addStudent(student):
    reg,year,degree,*name= student.strip().split()
    fullName = "%s, %s" % (name[-1], " ".join(name[:-1]))
    return (reg, year, degree, name, fullName)
```

Comment: What does `"%s, %s" %` part do? I don't quite understand the percentage signs, could you explain a bit thanks

Comment: The `"%s, %s" % (value1, value2)` is [old style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 1):

Or change that line

```
fullName = name[0] + ", " + " ".join(name[1:])
```

to this

```
fullName = name[0] + ", " + " ".join(name[-1:0:-1])
```

Edit:

```
dat = '1234567 1 C100 Bartholomew Homer Simpson'

def addStudent(student):
    reg,year,degree,*name= student.strip().split(" ")
    name = list(reversed(name))
#    You have now:: 
#        name = ['Simpson', 'Homer', 'Bartholomew']
#    Therefore , name[-1:0:-1]  
#        will select from last item in list 'Bartholomew to 
#        the 0th one, the 0th  being excluded in reverse   
    fullName = name[0] + ", " + " ".join(name[-1:0:-1])

    return (reg,year,degree,name,fullName)

def printStud(studentTuple):
    reg,year,degree,*name,fullName = studentTuple
    reg = int(reg)
    thisYear = "Year "+str(year)
    print(format(fullName, "<32s")+format(reg,"<7d")+format(degree,">6s"),format(thisYear,">6s"))
```

Output :

```
 In [1]:
 Simpson, Bartholomew Homer      1234567  C100 Year 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need sorted names, you can sort them using `sorted()`

```
a=["metallica", "therion", "acdc"]
print a[0],", "+" ".join( sorted(a[1:]))
```

out:

> metallica , acdc therion